# statement select with value in label

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I make a statement in below but its showing the statement instead of value

```
 Dim amt As String = Nothing
            amt = "select amount from [xx].[dbo].[xx] where referance_number=" & Page.Request.QueryString("trackidx") & ""
            Dim objs As New DATAAccess
            objs.insert_dataset_Access_accdb_test(amt)

            vpc_Amount.Text = amt
```

Comment: amt is a String, so the behaviour is logic

Comment: @ahmed you can't get value like that, except  if `insert_dataset_Access_accdb_test` Should return value and we can't Know that if we didn't see the code.

Comment: the result showing {select amount from [xx].[dbo].[xx] where referance_number=3}

Comment: `?trackidx=0;DROP TABLE [xx].[dbo].[xx];`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Show code of `objs.insert_dataset_Access_accdb_test` method

Comment: `amt = "SELECT ...`, then you `vpc_Amount.Text = amt`, so application do what you want. Show code where you read value